# How to put a class-diagram under version control?

Tags: github, uml, class-diagram

I want to upload a class-diagram to a public repository on GitHub.

Is there any tool which is considered to be a convention for this purpose?

Currently, I am using Google Docs, from which I can export a PDF.

Someone has suggested for me to use https://www.draw.io/, from which I can export an XML (which would be a lot more suitable for version control, since it is pure text), but I don't know whether or not this tool is "well accepted" across the community.

Comment: I think, it is a very useful question and a good practice, if done correctly, of course. +1

Comment: I do not understand attempts to close: UML is in theme, version systems too. How their combination can be off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

1. All versions control systems work with text files. PDF is not a text file. Forget it. It is the same as putting exe files under version control. VCSs work with **source** files, don't forget this.
2. All diagrams editors has inner representations of diagrams in some sort of text file. Eclipse UML editors use XML. So, the versions control systems can easily take these files and work with them.
3. The problem comes when you have conflicts. You will have to resolve them reading and understanding the inner language of the diagram representation. It could be very difficult.

So, it is possible, but try to minimize the conflicts.

Comment: Thank you. I don't entirely agree with the comparison between EXE and PDF, because PDF do essentially contain a lot of textual data, and are even comparable by diff tools such as Beyond Compare.

Comment: But I do understand (from #2) the mistake of using Google Docs for a diagrams editor.

Comment: @goodvibration And you can EDIT the pdf for removing conflicts?

Comment: As for Google Docs - I never used it for diagrams. The main question is if you can edit diagrams by editing the representation file.

Comment: No, I cannot edit the PDF, only the source (in this case, my Google Docs file). Good point!

Comment: As for tools, Eclipse has many UML editors, I don't remember the name of the best one. The free version of VP is also OK - but I didn't look at the inner language there.